# Create a kable in R from specific vector values

Tags: r, kable

So I'm trying to create a kable in R from the data set "mydata" based on a specific set of values, outliers in this case, and I can't find the correct context:

```
# this pulls out the outliers from the RATIO boxplot data
RT_outliers = (boxplot(mydata$RATIO, plot=FALSE)$out)

#below is my best shot so far as to how to create a table that 
#contains just the rows that have the outlier values
kable(mydata$[mydata$RATIO==RT_outliers])
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

the dollar after mydata is the issue
also, you need to add a coma because you're filtering rows

```
# this pulls out the outliers from the RATIO boxplot data
RT_outliers = (boxplot(mydata$RATIO, plot=FALSE)$out)

#below is my best shot so far as to how to create a table that 
#contains just the rows that have the outlier values
kable(mydata[mydata$RATIO==RT_outliers,])
```

Comment: Thanks, I got an error when I ran your code "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length", so i found this option and it worked:              kable(subset(mydata, mydata$RATIO %in% boxplot(mydata$RATIO, plot=FALSE)$out))

Comment: can you share the mydata file?

Comment: I can, just not sure how to attach a .csv

Comment: I had written that before reading that you already fixed your issue. ignore me then :)